# Multiple months counts in one query

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database in which i have a list of persons and the time data , so i'ts like

```
user_firstname  | report_date
Alan            | 2020-04-12
Alex            | 2020-04-11
Miranda         | 2020-04-11
Joseph          | 2020-04-11
Alex            | 2020-04-10
```

I want to count for each user how many times did he report in a month

```
SELECT user_firstname, user_lastname, count(*) as number 
FROM table 
WHERE MONTH(report_date) = 5 
GROUP BY user_email
```

and here I get the number of how many times did they do a report in 5th month, how can i connect all months in the same query?

my wish to get output like this:

```
user_firstname  | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May ....other months
Alan            |  2  |  6  | 10  |  1  |  8
Alex            |  5  |  1  |  3  |  7  |  28
Miranda         |  2  |  5  |  2  |  5  |  18
Joseph          |  1  |  0  |  0  | 25  |  8
Alex            |  7  |  9  |  1  |  2  |  58
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use group by month() to

```
SELECT  MONTH(report_date), user_firstname, user_lastname, count(*) as number 
FROM table 
GROUP BY user_email, MONTH(report_date)
```

for what in your comment

```
    SELECT   user_firstname, user_lastname
        , sum( month(report_date) = 1) Jan 
        , sum( month(report_date) = 2) Feb 
        , sum( month(report_date) = 3) Mar  
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY user_email
```